# React AG Grid custom sort for date and time using format MM/DD/YYYY ##:##AM or PM

Tags: reactjs, sorting, ag-grid

Using React AG Grid I am trying to sort in descending order the by date and time. Example data below. Setting sortable to true sorts the dates correctly but not the time.

```
10/31/2022  8:00AM
12/31/2022  4:59PM
12/12/2022  3:00PM
10/31/2022  7:00PM
10/31/2022  7:00AM
```

Comment: Those results show no ordering at all. You didn't post any code so it's impossible to guess what's wrong. Check [Formatting, Sorting & Filtering Dates in ag-Grid](https://blog.ag-grid.com/valueformatters-part-2)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi to compare these dates, you need to provide a comparator in the column definition, and then the grid will know how to sort the column with the data you mentioned.

```
  const [columnDefs] = useState([
    ...
    { field: 'date', comparator: dateComparator, sort: 'desc' },
    ...
  ]);
```

For the example data, you provided, first convert it to a number.

```
// eg 08/29/2004 4:59PM gets converted to 20040829.1659
const monthToComparableNumber = (date) => {
  if (date === undefined || date === null || date.length !== 18) {
    return null;
  }

  const last = date.length;

  const yearNumber = Number.parseInt(date.substring(6, 10));
  const dayNumber = Number.parseInt(date.substring(3, 5));
  const monthNumber = Number.parseInt(date.substring(0, 2));

  const partOfDay = date.substring(last - 2, last) == 'PM' ? 0.12 : 0;
  const strHour = String(Number(date.substring(last - 7, last - 5)));

  const hour =
    strHour.length == 2 ? Number('0.' + strHour) : Number('0.0' + strHour);
  const h24 = partOfDay + hour;

  const minutes = Number('0.00' + date.substring(last - 4, last - 2));

  return yearNumber * 10000 + monthNumber * 100 + dayNumber + h24 + minutes;
};
```

You can use the **monthToComparableNumber()** in the comparator function.

```
const dateComparator = (date1, date2) => {
  const date1Number = monthToComparableNumber(date1);
  const date2Number = monthToComparableNumber(date2);
  if (date1Number === null && date2Number === null) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (date1Number === null) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (date2Number === null) {
    return 1;
  }
  return date1Number - date2Number;
};
```

I made an AG Grid React example in plunker with your example data.
the code from above is used in the example below:
https://plnkr.co/edit/f25Bgp9a34vpbbTT?open=index.jsx

Comment: I did some more testing and it doesn't quite work right. It's not sorting correctly for dates such as 9/17/2022 8:00AM. Also, some times that are 10:00PM are not sorting correctly.

Comment: You are correct it will not work with 9/17/2022

it should be 09/17/2022, as shown in the comment above the code

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the example to account for the date format mentioned in the comment.

```
const dateAndTimeComparableNumber = (date) => {
// convert date and time to a comparable number
// eg 08/29/2004 4:59PM gets converted to 20040829.1659
// format - D/MM/YYYY ##:##AM or PM
// format - DD/MM/YYYY ##:##AM or PM
  if (
    (date === undefined || date === null,
    date.length !== 17 && date.length !== 18)
  ) {
    return null;
  }

  const last = date.length;

  const [monthNumber, dayNumber, yearNumber] = date
    .split(/[\/ ]/)
    .slice(0, 3)
    .map((partOfDate) => Number(partOfDate));

  const partOfDay = date.substring(last - 2, last) == 'PM' ? 0.12 : 0;
  const strHour = String(Number(date.substring(last - 7, last - 5)));

  const hour =
    strHour.length == 2 ? Number('0.' + strHour) : Number('0.0' + strHour);
  const h24 = partOfDay + hour;

  const minutes = Number('0.00' + date.substring(last - 4, last - 2));

  return yearNumber * 10000 + monthNumber * 100 + dayNumber + h24 + minutes;
};
```

**working example**: https://plnkr.co/edit/Vqz3zObzuRV9a50M?open=index.jsx